# Issue in using checkbox in sign up form in Codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter, checkbox

My sign up form was previously working well. However, I had to add an acceptance page or terms and conditions before sign up can be successful. I thought it would be better to include it in sign up page rather than after sign up (before being presented with member's homepage). Problem is, it's having a lot of issues. It's not working properly.

Here's my code in view page: (i added this at the bottom of all fields before sign up button)

```
Please proceed only if you accept our <a target="blank" href="<?php site_url("in/terms_and_conditions");?>">terms and conditions</a>.
<input type='checkbox' name='terms' value='checked' id='terms' required autofocus/><br/>
```

Right now, it seems to work fine (codeigniter built in validation prompts up a message telling the user to click before he can proceed). Issue is 1. the link ("in/terms_and_conditions") does not show properly. Whenever the corresponding text is clicked, instead of showing the proper page, it just opens up a new sign up page.
Second issue is the presence of errors as follows:
    Message: Undefined index: c_terms  in model Line Number: 24
Line 24 is this:

```
'terms'=> $post_obj['c_terms']
```

I tried to add this to my array. Was it actually correct?
The second error shown is:

Column 'terms' cannot be null

```
INSERT INTO `client` (`first_name`, `last_name`, `email_address`, `password`, `address`, `tagline`, `profile`, `interests`, `billing_mode`, `terms`) VALUES ('dsfhkds', 'hfdskhflk', 'test@yahoo.com', '123456', 'fsdkfhsdk', 'sdkfhsdkf', 'sdklhfslkdhflsdhf', 'kdslhflks', 'Escrow', NULL)
```

What I did to my original table is I added column which I named "terms", set it to text type and no default value.

Please help me fix this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Issue 1:** 
Did you create the page "in/terms_and_conditions" ? make sure?

Controller Name: in

Action Name : terms_and_conditions

**Issue 2:**
You have named checkbox as "terms". then, you should get the posted value as follows

```
'terms'=> $post_obj['terms']
```

**Issue 3:**
Set "terms" column default value as "NULL"

Comment: thanks for your response. when I changed default value to NULL, i got an error. well probably because I set type in the db as text, what should it be instead

Answer (score 0):

I see three problems:

1. You're not echoing the result of the `site_url` function. Just put `echo` in front of it.
2. If `$post_obj` is your '$_POST`array you have to use the`name` attribute of the HTML input as the key:

   `'terms' => $post_obj['terms']`
3. Your problem is that you're not setting any text to be saved in `terms`. Add it to the second parameter of `$this->db->insert('table', $data)` like this: `$data['terms'] = '...'`

Comment: Hi, the answer to number 1 echo worked. Thanks! I've adjusted what I had in my sign up form as well, I named it "c_terms", I think it must be working

Comment: After I adjusted echo and terms into c_terms in my sign up form, it's now working well. Thanksss!

Comment: I wanted to vote for both your answers as they both helped me with my issue. However, it seems that only one gets voted. I hope you don't mind if I give the point to Asik for now.. he was right, the terms I created was not in the proper location. I also have not loaded it in my controller's page, but you were also right that I only had to echo it out..